# How to Change Access log From Hourly to Daily or Weekly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, access-log

I try to follow the instructions in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs to create access log for my bucket in Google Cloud Platform. The problem is that the access log is created hourly, which means in one day, there will be 24 files and for one week, there will be 24 * 7 files. That is not convenient to manage.

Is it possible to create access log daily or weekly? Or auto merge all hourly logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the frequency of these logs creation. However, you could create a Cloud Functions that is triggered every day or week and merges all the logs into one CSV. [Here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-cloud-function-to-automate-google-spreadsheet-csv-import-d2ffb8fbe9b4) I found a blog that explains how to do it and may be useful for you.

Also, I have created a feature request and you can follow its progress in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127911979)